# Is there a way to generate the aggregated schema.json for two or more GraphQL services?

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-java

I have several GraphQL services under a federation.
I start one service and download the schema.json for that particular service:

```
apollo schema:download --endpoint=http://localhost:9001/graphql schema.json
```

I've followed this to download schema.json -> https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/downloading-schema/

Is there a way to generate the aggregated schema.json for two or more GraphQL services?

Something like :

`apollo schema:download --endpoint1=http://localhost:9001/graphql --endpoint2=http://localhost:9002/graphql ... schema.json`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do this with the apollo cli. But, you can do something like:

```sh
apollo schema:download --endpoint=http://localhost:9001/graphql schema1.json
apollo schema:download --endpoint=http://localhost:9002/graphql schema2.json
```

After you can merge both with any merge tool you want.

Another way can be the npm package [GraphQL Code Generator](https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/). There you can specify more sources of your schema.

Comment: Can you please suggest any good merge tool I can use for this?

Comment: I am not familier with the json structure of your schema and it also depends on your environment. But https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/jq/ is in a lot cases a solid choice.

Comment: @PrashantKumar Please share your solution how did you merge the 2 schemas?